# How to decode (very large in value) hex string into decimal?

Tags: python, hex, blockchain, ethereum

I was trying to decode hex strings similar to the following format:

```
0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000bf97e2a21966df7fe
```

I was able to decode it with the [online calculator](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.htm). The correct decoded number should be `220892037897060743166`.

However, when I am trying to decode it with python with the following code, it returns error:

```
"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000bf97e2a21966df7fe".decode("hex")

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-1cf86ff46cbc> in <module>()
      9 key=keyarr[0]
     10 
---> 11 "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000bf97e2a21966df7fe".decode("hex")

/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/hex_codec.py in hex_decode(input, errors)
     40     """
     41     assert errors == 'strict'
---> 42     output = binascii.a2b_hex(input)
     43     return (output, len(input))
     44 

TypeError: Non-hexadecimal digit found
```

Then I removed the 0x in the front of the hex number and tried again:

```
"00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000bf97e2a21966df7fe".decode("hex")
```

Then the output became:

```
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b\xf9~*!\x96m\xf7\xfe'
```

I actually don't understand the output ...

In case you are wondering where do those numbers come from, they are from [Ethereum blockchain (ERC20) tokens](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23393/ethereum-token-divide-value-by-1018/23395).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call `int` on it with a base of 16:

```
int(your_string, base=16)
```

`.decode('hex')` means you want to treat the string as a sequence of hex encodings of individual characters.

Answer (score 0):

with python 3.6.1

```
>>> a = '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000bf97e2a21966df7fe'
>>> a
'0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000bf97e2a21966df7fe'
>>> int(a, 16)
220892037897060743166
```